# Can you escape the vault in framing the frame while solo

Tags: payday-2

On day 3 of Framing Frame after you've done everything you have the option of getting the gold out of the vault. You can deactivate the lasers using the keyboard in the office giving you enough time to run down to the vault, grab some gold and get out before the lasers turn on.

If you are too slow (or too ambitious) you can get stuck in the vault when the lasers turn on.

Is there any way to get out of the vault when this happens without setting all the alarms off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, you cannot escape without setting off the alarm if this happens. Since you can't turn off the lasers inside the vault, and you don't have someone else to turn them off for you, you're stuck. Your options at that point are to either reset or set off the alarm and hope for the best. No calling for help, either, because anyone who drops in will spawn where you are (stuck inside).

Comment: In addition, getting a friend to join *after* you're stuck in the vault will not help either as new players always spawn where the host is, (in this case) inside the vault.

Comment: @3ventic: That's really useful to know in fact since I was idly wondering if that would help. I usually play offline though unless I know I'm expecting a friend so I couldn't do that even if I wanted to usually.